# What is the command to add all changes except bin folder in GIT?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have an Android project in GIT. I want to commit all changes but don't want to commit the bin folder. Is there any command to commit all except the bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the bin folder to the `.gitignore` file like so:

```
bin/
```

if the bin folder is already tracked even though you've added it to the gitignore you can:

```
git rm -r --cached bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add bin to your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the bin folder in the `.gitignore`